# An estimate involving exponentials of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, and let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on $H$.

I've seen it written in a book that for $x,y\in[0,1]$, we have
$$\|e^{ixT}-e^{iyT}\|\leq\|T\|\|x-y\|.$$

**Question:** How would one prove this, and where are the hypotheses (self-adjointness of $T$ and $x,y\in[0,1]$) needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
e^{ixT} - e^{iyT} &= \int_0^1 (e^{i(y+ t(x-y)) T})' dt \\
&= \int_0^1 e^{i(y+t(x-y)T} (i(x-y)T)dt\end{align}

So
$$\|e^{ixT} - e^{iyT}\| \le \|T\| |x-y| \int_0^1 \| e^{i(y+t(x-y)T}\|dt$$

Since $T$ is self adjoint, $e^{irt}$ is unitrary:

$$ (e^{irT})^* = e^{-ir T^*} = e^{-irT} = (e^{irT})^{-1}, $$
we have
$$ \| e^{irT}\|=1$$ and thus

$$\|e^{ixT} - e^{iyT}\| \le \|T\| |x-y|. $$

The fact that $x, y\in [0,1]$ is not used, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming WLOG that  $x≤y$, one has by the mean value Theorem that
$$
  \|e^{ixT}-e^{iyT}\| ≤
  \int_x^y\left\|{d\over dt} e^{itT}\right\| dt =
  \int_x^y\|iTe^{itT}\| dt =
  \int_x^y\|T\| dt =
  \|T\|  |x-y|
  $$

Comment: That is the same idea of @ArcticChar's answer but I am posting it just because it might be a bit more concise and it was already all typed up when I saw their post!